# Python for testing of wav files using UBM

Tags: python, scipy, covariance, gmm

While using scipy.stats.multivariate_normal how can I use a diagonal covariance matrix of dimension 128 * 39 using python.
I am implementing UBM and need some information about testing of a sound wav file given I have adapted parameters.

Comment: A covariance matrix with dimension 128 * 39 doesn't make sense.  Please explain your problem in more detail.  What is UBM?

Comment: This is basically a diagonal matrix and I have 128 such matrix. UBM is Universal Background Machine which is used in speaker recognition

Comment: Those details (and more, preferably) should be in the question.

Comment: ok, so how can i use a diagonal matrix for multivariate_normal?

Comment: It looks like the `multivariate_normal` methods can only handle one covariance matrix at a time.  If the `cov` argument is a 1-D array, the methods assume that it is the diagonal of the covariance matrix.  If you want to evaluate one of the methods for 128 different covariance matrices, you'll have to write a loop and call it 128 times.